# fatal error: pthread/pthread_impl.h: No such file or directory #include <pthread/pthread_impl.h>

Tags: linux, gcc, terminal, compiler-errors, gnu

I have compiled and seen those error sentences

```
/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/pthread.h:57:34: fatal error: 
pthread/pthread_impl.h: No such file or directory
#include <pthread/pthread_impl.h>
```

I have found pthread.h and pthread_impl.h independently but there is no header file named **pthread/pthread_impl.h**(Also I moved pthread.h and pthread_impl.h in compile path each but It made same error)

What should I do...?

Answer (score 0):

- Have you added the pthread compiler flag? (`-pthread`)
- The correct include file is `pthread.h`.